# Iterating within a partial view using model only works when not using partialview

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I´m trying to get some posts from the database. It works fine when opening in the posts index page but not in the main index. As a partialview, I have created a `PostViewModel` for the `PostModel`.

Here´s the code:

In Index.cshtml (Post):

```
@model IEnumerable<Project.Models.Post>

@foreach (var item in Model) { @item.Name }
```

In Index.cshtml (Main):

```
@model Project.Models.ViewModels.PostViewModel

@Html.Partial("~/Views/Posts/Index.cshtml", Model)
```

When I run the project, it complains about a *System.NullReferenceException*
in the `foreach` loop.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Your code is supposed to be `@model IEnumerable<Post>`

Comment: I have it but for some reason does that part of the code not appear here

Comment: this part: @model IEnumerable<Project.Models.Post>

Comment: As a best practice you should check if model is not null before the for each loop. Also debug your controller to make sure you pass the data in the argument to the view.

Comment: Additionally  ensure that the data type your passing to the view  and the one in the partial view are same as the model

Comment: Please try to fix  your title - is "partial view" and "partialview" the same? Please try to be consistent so that the quality of the questions does not suffer. Thanks and welcome.

Comment: It looks like the data types are not the same.  in Main/Index you are passing `Model` which is a `PostViewModel` into the Post/Index view, which is expecting a `collection of Post (eg. IEnumerable<Post>)`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: The code you have shown would throw a _The model item passed into the dictionary is of type .. but this dictionary requires a model item of type_ so you have not even shown the correct code.

Answer (score 0):

When you are passing Model from the main view to `@Html.Partial` it is not able to convert it to `IEnumerable<Post>` , which is expected by the partial view, that's why you see the NullReferenceException.

If you have a property in the PostViewModel class which is represents collection of Post then you should try passing that in the `@Html.Partial`

Let say you have a property Posts of type `List<Post>` in class PostViewModel then you should use it as following.

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Posts/Index.cshtml", Model.Posts)
```

Answer (score 0):

When the partial view is "called" the Model variable is internally set with

```
Model = instance as IEnumerable<Project.Models.Post>;
```

The instance you are passing is of type `Project.Models.Post` so it cannot be converted to `IEnumerable<Project.Models.Post>`. And that is the reason why `Model` is `null` inside the partial view.